# SQLAlchemy: How can I create a hybrid property for the disjunction of columns?

Tags: python, properties, sqlalchemy

I have a User class which stores a "first_name" column and an "alias" column to describe a person's name and their nickname. I want to be able to query this class to find users by either their first_name or their alias, so I wrote my class like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(64))
    alias = Column(String(64), nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        return self.alias or self.first_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'User("{}" a.k.a. "{}")'.format(self.first_name, self.alias)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This almost works. I'm able to search for users by their first name. But I'm not able to search for users by their aliases.

```
>>> session = Session()
>>> user = User(first_name="Edward", alias="Ed")
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.flush()
>>> session.query(User).filter_by(name="Edward").first()
User("Edward" a.k.a. "Ed")
>>> session.query(User).filter_by(name="Ed").first()
>>>
```

This makes sense-- the expressions generated by `name` are not the ones I want.

```
>>> print session.query(User).filter_by(name="Ed")
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".first_name AS user_first_name, "user".alias AS user_alias
FROM "user"
WHERE "user".first_name = :first_name_1
```

The [SQLAlchemy docs on hybrid properties](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) seems to suggest the solution is use [hybrid_property.expression()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) to change the generated expression. However, I can't see what expression would make sense to return.

My first idea was to return some sort of `OR`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_

@name.expression
def name(cls):
    return or_(cls.first_name, cls.alias)
```

But the expressions it generates are predictably wrong:

```
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".first_name AS user_first_name, "user".alias AS user_alias
FROM "user"
WHERE ("user".first_name OR "user".alias) = :param_1
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more studying and experimentation, it turns out the solution is described in the "[Building Custom Comparators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators)" section. You can use a Comparator object to implement custom comparisons:

```
class Either(Comparator):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return or_(other == self.left, other == self.right)


class User(Base):
    # ...

    @name.comparator
    def name(self):
        return Either(self.first_name, self.alias)
```

Which works as expected:

```
>>> user
User("Edward" a.k.a. "Ed")
>>> print session.query(User).filter_by(name="Edward")
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".first_name AS user_first_name, "user".alias AS user_alias
FROM "user"
WHERE "user".first_name = :first_name_1 OR "user".alias = :alias_1
>>> print session.query(User).filter_by(name="Edward").first()
User("Edward" a.k.a. "Ed")
>>> print session.query(User).filter_by(name="Ed").first()
User("Edward" a.k.a. "Ed")
```

I think there is more room improvement here by studying the "[Hybrid Value Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#hybrid-value-objects)", however, it's still evading me.